# How do I display a list of audio files from directory to then select one to play?

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm making a list where files are loaded on the browser. I want to select a file from the list and choose to play it.

[image: Illustration]

Right now, I have a list of the files in the path, and and audio player in the cell on the right that plays the audio of the file that is in the directory.

This displays the list but I can't do anything with it.

```
<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
    <tbody>  
        @if (filesList != null && filesList.Count > 0)
            {
                int auF = 0;
                @foreach (string file in filesList)
                {    auF++;
                     <tr> 
                         <td>
                             <span>@auF.</span>
                             <span @onclick="@(e=>readFile(file))" style="cursor:pointer;">@file</span>
                             </td> <td>
                             <audio controls="controls">
                                 <source src="@file">
                             </audio>
                        </td> 
                     </tr>
                }
            }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td>No files</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Code part:

```
@code{
List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
string path = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\path"}";

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        filesList.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
}

public void readFile(string fileName)
{
}}
```

Does anyone know how I can make a file list selectable, so that I can get to choose which audio file to play by clicking on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML Audio player can accept `URL` or `base64` string of an audio file.

In that case, I would recommend you store the audio files in `wwwroot` folder as web assets eg. inside `wwwroot\audio\`. Then the HTML audio player can access these audio files by their `url`.

Additionally, I created the class `AudioFile` to store the audio file properties such as the last modified date and file size so that we can show that information too in the table as well.

[image: wwwroot audio files]

Implementation:

```razor
@page "/"
@inject IWebHostEnvironment env

<table class="table mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Last Modified</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
            <th scope="col">Player</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if (audioList.Count > 0)
    {
        @foreach (var file in audioList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@(audioList.IndexOf(file) + 1)</td>
                <td>@file.Name</td>
                <td>@file.LastModified.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm")</td>
                <td>@FileSizeFormatter.FormatSize(file.Length)</td>
                <td>
                    <audio controls="controls">
                        <source src="@file.Url">
                    </audio>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <tr>
            <td>No files</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```cs
@code{
    readonly List<AudioFile> audioList = new();
    readonly string audioFolderName = "audio";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var path = $"{env.WebRootPath}\\{audioFolderName}\\";
        var d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var files = d.GetFiles();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            audioList.Add(new AudioFile
            {
                Name = file.Name,
                Url = $"/audio/{file.Name}",
                Length = file.Length,
                LastModified = file.LastWriteTime
            });
        }
    }

    public class AudioFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public long Length { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    }

    public static class FileSizeFormatter
    {
        static readonly string[] suffixes = { "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB" };

        public static string FormatSize(long bytes)
        {
            var counter = 0;
            decimal number = bytes;
            while (Math.Round(number / 1024) >= 1)
            {
                number = number / 1024;
                counter++;
            }
            return $"{number:n1}{suffixes[counter]}";
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:
[image: audio player blazor]

Comment: Thank you very much!! Btw do you know if it is possible to make the name of the file a button that starts the audio?

Comment: @Addlon I don't understand why you would want to click on the file name link instead of the actual `audio` element which has the play button. Can you clarify your scenario?

Comment: @Addlon Do you want to have a list of audio files in a table and only one main `audio` element outside the table (not in every row like in your code), so that when you click on the file name, the audio element plays that selected audio?

Comment: Yes. Having 1 audio element would be preferable.

Comment: @Addlon If you could haved described that clearly in the question it would have been better and efficient, but your question was general and not focused on exactly what you wanted. You can accept this answer and ask a new question clearly and will be there to answer it.

Comment: I have posted another question that should encapsulates the matter more precisely.